# How to make a link on month of jQuery Datepicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

My task is showing news of the selected day when user will click on the day field of then calendar and show all news of the month when user will click on the month name of the calendar.

I use jQuery Datepicker in inline display mode.

I cannot do the second task. How to make a link on month of jQuery Datepicker?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add

```
$('.ui-datepicker-month').live('click',function(){
        //do your code 
}); 



<style>

.ui-datepicker-month:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
}

</style>
```

Comment: may be the id of the calander month is different , check it and add your one , this is working . i tested it  .    :)

Answer (score 0):

It is a link that is shown, so you're probably just worried about the style. Customize the jQuery stylesheet to display it in your own link style.